# How to load json file in handlebarjs

Tags: handlebars.js

I need to  fetch the contents from json and render it to my templates.
I tried with inline json format, its working fine.
please help me  to load the external json file located in other directory or from other servers.

**Inline script**

```
  var src = document.getElementById("semantic-template").innerHTML;
  var tmpl = Handlebars.compile(src);
  var json = {"leagueName":"American League", "abbr":"AL", "teams":[
            {"teamName":"Tampa Bay", "w":96, "l":66},
            {"teamName":"NY Yankees", "w":95, "l":67}};
   document.getElementById("content-template").innerHTML = tmpl(json);
```

**HTML**

```
  <div id="content-template"></div>
  <script id="semantic-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   <caption>{{leagueName}}</caption>
  </script>
```

**My external json format**

```
[{
    "pics" : "images/item-1.png",
    "label" : "Careers",
    "text" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
}]
```

Please provide the suggestions for this

Comment: For what <caption>{{heading}}</caption> is intended for ?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

Tried with jquery method getJson and the data are getting displayed on my views

```
 $.getJSON("assests/json/carousel-data.json", function(data) {
    $("#content-template").html(tmpl({objects:data}));
 });
```